# Converting big endian to little endian or vice versa

Tags: c, embedded, firmware

Update: The implementation is in C

I am trying to write a endianess conversion function

My understanding is that the endianess conversion in both ways uses the same function as it is a byte reversal.

I have two implementations.

Method 1

Get each byte at lsb and OR with result and left shift my result

```
unsigned int convert_endian(unsigned int num)
{
       unsigned int res=0;
       int i = 0;
       while(i < sizeof(int))
       {
            res = res << 8;
            res |= num & 0xFF;
            num = num >> 8;
            i++;
       }
       
       return res;
}
```

Method 2

Use a char pointer to get each byte and OR it into the result

```
unsigned int convert_endian_char(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int res=0;
    char *ptr = (char*)&num;
    int i=0;
    while(i<sizeof(int))
    {
        res = res << 8;
        res |= *ptr & 0xFF;
        i++;
        ptr++;
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

The code seems to work
Eg:
For num = 0x12345678 I get res = 0x78563412

But during code review I was told this wouldn't work and I would lose bytes in the Method 1 during shifts.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you are then I am missing it as well.

Comment: Please use only the C++ or the C tag according to what you are actually writing. Answer are generally different for the two languages. For example for C++ someone is likely going to suggest https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/byteswap. (Your code also looks ok to me with the assumption of `CHAR_BIT == 8`.)

Comment: Looks fine to me. There are a few stylistic improvements I'd make, but the logic seems ok.

Comment: *Am I missing something here?* Yes, the question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should challenge the reviewer to present a failure case for method 1.  Whatever effect they are looking at, I think they are mistaken about it causing the function to produce incorrect results.

Comment: @273K, the question belongs on CodeReview only if the OP is prepared to assert that it works correctly. But that's exactly the question posed: *does* the code work correctly?

Comment: @JohnBollinger *does the code work correctly?* is a review question.

Comment: Oddly enough, method 2 *is* flawed, and you didn't mention the reviewer complaining about that one.  Method two works only if native byte order is little-endian.

Comment: @273K, from [the help docs for Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "If you have a **working piece of code** [...]" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Continue reading that page: *you are looking for open-ended feedback in the following areas: ... **Correctness in unanticipated cases***

Comment: Here's my generic answer: [How to swap the bytes in any basic data type or array of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64056527/4561887)

Comment: @JohnBollinger My understanding is that if the native is little endian, then char pointer points at LSByte, and if big-endian then at the MSByte. Then we can iterate through individual bytes to form the reversed byte order. Could you elaborate on why it would fail on big endian machine?  Thanks for the pointing out codereview space

Comment: @user3280530, in method 2, you extract bytes one by one, from lowest address to highest address, and order them so that the first-extracted becomes the MSB of the result, the second becomes the next most significant, *etc*.  That effects an order reversal when the bytes are initially ordered from LSB to MSB, but it reproduces the original byte order if they are initially ordered MSB to LSB.  And it scrambles things in interesting ways if the native byte order is something else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7184905/3280530 adding this link for ref

Answer (score 4):

Candidate problems with method 1.

All problems are obscure.

- `res = res << 8; res |= num & 0xFF;` fails for machines where `char` is not 8-bit.  (Rare.)  Better as `res = res << CHAR_BIT; res |= num & UCHAR_MAX;` if trying to swap "bytes", as locally defined.
- If `unsigned` is neither *big* nor *little* endian like [PDP-11-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Hardware), the correctness of code to achieve swapping big/little endian is doubtful.  (Very rare.)
- If `sizeof(char) == sizeof(unsigned)`, (very rare) we are going to have troubles as no loop needed - depending on goals.
- Not really an issue here, yet better to not mix type sign-ness: `int i = 0; while(i < sizeof(int))` --> `unsigned /* or size_t */ i = 0; while(i < sizeof(int))`.
- Not really an issue here as `sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned)`, yet better to not introduce `int` anywhere in this code.  .

Nothing matches the "lose bytes in the Method 1 during shifts." assertion.

Perhaps:

1. The interviewer was *mistakenly* thinking `res << 8` leads to UB (undefined behavior) when shifting into the sign bit.  Yet since `unsigned`, there is no sign bit and no UB.
2. `num = num >> 8;` destroys the original value of `num`.  But so what?  `num` preservation is not needed.
3. The interviewer was purposely challenging OP with an unsupported claim, to assess how OP handled it.
4. Code posted is not *exactly* the same code as in the interview.  It is amazing how even a single character difference can mean a lot.

I suspect 3 or 4.

Alternative:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>

unsigned swap_endian_big_little(unsigned num) {
  unsigned res = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof res; i++) {
    res <<= CHAR_BIT;
    res |= num & UCHAR_MAX;
    num >>= CHAR_BIT;
  }

  return res;
}
```

---

No review of method 2 other than [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370307/converting-big-endian-to-little-endian-or-vice-versa?noredirect=1#comment136398632_77370307)
 and `char *ptr` better as `unsigned char *ptr` to handle various *signed* encodings.

---

> My understanding is that the endianess conversion in both ways uses the same function as it is a byte reversal.

True for big/little endian, yet other endian are possible.

*Usually* the coding goal is not to swap endian from big-to-little or little-to-big, but to swap from native-to-big, native-to-little, big-to-native, or little-to-native.

Comment: You state that "`num` preservation is not needed" but don't explain why.  Of course it's because `num` was passed by value and is completely local to the function, and any modifications are also local and don't affect the rest of the program.

Comment: Umm, did you test the "alternative"? Some typos: `<<=`

Comment: @Lundin Unfortunately I  did not test the latest edit.  Code amended.  Curiosly I did not need `#include <stddef.h>`

Comment: Maybe you included `stdio.h` "off camera"?

Comment: @Lundin `swap_endian_big_little()` compiles without `<stddef.h>` and _only_ `<limits.h>`.  `UCHAR_MAX` and `CHAR_BIT` are specified to be defined via `<limits.h>`.  What did you find was missing with only `<limits.h>`?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qKof5hzzG And that's gcc in lax mode, not in strict mode.

Comment: @Lundin Interesting.  `size_t` is the definition missing.  Although I have many gcc warnings enabled (-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wstrict-prototypes), still does not flag missing `size_t`. Any recommended settings?

Comment: I have no clue... maybe some sneaky left-over make file or hard-to-find IDE setting behind it all?

Answer (score 2):

No need to overthink it. Something like this should be portable between big/little endian:

```
#define IS_LITTLE ( *(uint8_t*)&(uint16_t){0xAABB} == 0xBB)

uint32_t flip_endian32 (uint32_t in)
{
  const uint8_t* n = (const uint8_t*)&in;

  return ((uint32_t)n[IS_LITTLE ? 0u : 3u] << 24u) |
         ((uint32_t)n[IS_LITTLE ? 1u : 2u] << 16u) |
         ((uint32_t)n[IS_LITTLE ? 2u : 1u] <<  8u) |
         ((uint32_t)n[IS_LITTLE ? 3u : 0u] <<  0u) ;
}
```

gcc 12.3 -O3:

```
flip_endian32:
    mov     eax, edi
    bswap   eax
    ret
```

Should be somewhat MISRA compliant, suitable for small microcontrollers and so on.

Comment: Since OP still hasn't clarified whether they want to ask about C or C++, I would suggest adding that this answer targets C. `IS_LITTLE` doesn't work in C++, nor with C++ compilers that I know of to support compound literals as an extension.

Comment: @user17732522 In case of C++, just write a lamba, throw some exception into the wild, go grab a coffee, write a couple of templates, resolve some static initialization order bugs, grab another coffee, discover a new form of undefined behavior, delete the whole branch in the VCS, roll back to vision 1, then just write a lambda. Repeat for a week or two and then you eventually have a program doing the above but in 15 instructions instead of 3.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the [morning chuckle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370307/converting-big-endian-to-little-endian-or-vice-versa/77371144#comment136406129_77372938).

Comment: @Lundin Minor: any reason for the `u` in `<< 24u`? Style?  The type of the shift amount does not affect the type of `>>` result.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The claim in the last line about MISRA compliance. If the intention is to create something unsigned, you have to use `u`/`U` suffix for MISRA. Even if it doesn't actually matter, like in this specific case.

Comment: @Lundin, Interesting - and in this case, IMHO, MIRSA [jumped the shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_the_shark).   [More](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65732536/2410359)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, I wrote that answer...? Anyway, the bottom line is to keep to a consistent coding style. If you intentionally leave out `u` from some unsigned constants, that's just strange. And also static analyzer tools are very likely too dumb to make special exceptions for certain operators - the state of all MISRA checker products in the year 2023 is still quite depressive.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica To quote MISRA's exact rationale: "The right hand operand of a shift operator should be of _essentially unsigned type_ to ensure that undefined behaviour does not result from a negative shift."  IMO this is perfectly reasonable and justified, I can endure typing some `u` if it means keeping such bugs out of the code.

Comment: @Lundin "unsigned type to ensure that undefined behaviour does not result from a negative shift.." only handles one end of the restricted range of a shift.   `(uint32_t)n[0] << (some_int_variable & 31)` shifts by an `int`, prevents UB from both ends of the restricted range.  Uncertain if MISRA complains.  Is so, it may want `some_unsigned_variable & 31u`.    My experience with MISRA is that it is a tool with a wide and tailorable range of pedantism that management sets too high.  IAC, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Seem, you miss about in common memory, one memory address can store content 1 byte.

So to convert endian (between big and little), you don't need to do any bitwise operation just handle your primitive type as array of byte and reverse it then everything done.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <inttypes.h>

template<typename T>
union MemAlias{
    T buff;
    std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)> mem;
}; //union is good for aliasing

template<typename T>
T convert_endian(T num)
{
    MemAlias<T> in{num}; // member order matter here, it will construct to first member
   
    MemAlias<T> out;

    std::copy(in.mem.rbegin(), in.mem.rend(), out.mem.begin());// just reverse

    return out.buff;
}

template<typename T>
void print_mem(T num){
    MemAlias<T> m{num};
    for(auto a:m.mem){
        std::cout << std::hex 
                  << static_cast<int>(a) // cast to int because cout try to print uint8_t as character
                  << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main(){
   unsigned int i = 0xaabbccdd;
   print_mem(i); //mostly little endian
   auto j = convert_endian(i);
   print_mem(j); //mostly big endian
   /*
   result:
   dd cc bb aa 
   aa bb cc dd 
   */
}
```

Comment: Might be a valid point, but it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: "_//union is good for aliasing_": It is undefined behavior in C++, although compilers generally support it for C compatibility.

Comment: In addition to the undefined behavior (in C++), this creates a bunch of extra overhead code just for the sake of checking off the use of some C++ features from a bucket list. I wouldn't advise to use C++ for embedded systems or anything similarly performance-critical.

Comment: @user17732522 I was miss `union is good for aliasing if all member have same size`.
or if you found undefined behavior in my code by using union, you can tell me.

Comment: "union is good for aliasing if all member have same size" Says who?

Comment: @JakkapongRattananen No, it is always UB in C++, but as I said, compilers usually still support it (to some degree) because it is permitted in C.

Comment: @user17732522 `alias`  what I meant, It's  same resource but different name. 
ex. [https://godbolt.org/z/M8e3YoY5o](https://godbolt.org/z/M8e3YoY5o)  This program work as I expect even use compiler optimization. Do you  see any `undefined behavior` in this?

Comment: @JakkapongRattananen Yes, accessing `cols` when you set `width` as active member of the union object causes undefined behavior as the compiler will tell you if you try to evaluate the function in a constant expression: https://godbolt.org/z/Ee6frxccn But as I said, compilers will compile it as expected regardless at runtime. They support union-based aliasing as an extension in C++ because it is supported in C.

Comment: @user17732522 That's your program now, It wasn't mine. I was mark volatile because I don't want It's produce constant.